# NetLogo: Problem when counting variable containing an agent

Tags: netlogo

I'm very new to netlogo and was working on "Follower" model.
In extending the model propositions there is a "what if two turtles are allowed to have the same leader?"
I was wondering if there is a way to count the number of followers in turtles
(something like

```
count follower
```

and then use it in a way like :

```
let candidate one-of (turtles-at xd yd) with [follower = nobody or count follower < 2]
```

which gives this error on runtime:

> COUNT expected input to be an agentset but got the turtle (turtle xxxx) instead.

I solved the problem with a hack (adding a new variable f-num and then incrementing it when a new turtle is attached to the current turtle, and selecting candidates with the condition f-num < 2) but wanted to know if there is a better way for such a problem

Comment: I think the title of the question doesn't help to imagine the content, given that "property" isn't part of the NetLogo vocabulary. Do you mean something like "NetLogo: Problem when counting variable containing an agent"? I would suggest an edit but the edit queue is full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the original statement for setting `follower` is

```
ask candidate [set follower myself]
```

and `myself` is not an agentset, is an agent. This means that, unless that statement changes, `follower` is never going to be something countable: you can count how many agents are there in an agentset (which could also be an agentset of 1 or of 0), but you cannot count an agent.

The solution then has to be to change that statement, initialising `follower` as a different object - one that accommodates multiplicity (which means one on which you can perform an addition and one that you can measure).

1. **Solution with agentset**

As I said, agentsets can be counted. Actually, agentsets are the natural type of object that `count` operates on. Therefore, we could initialise `follower` as an agentset.
A way to do it is by using [turtle-set](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtle-set):

```
...
ask candidate [set follower (turtle-set follower myself)]
...
```

In that case, for consistency I would also change the `create-turtles population` bit by doing:

```
...
set follower (turtle-set)
...
```

This way, `follower` will be an agentset for all turtles since the beginning (starting as an empty agentset instead than as `nobody`).
I would much prefer it for consistency, but pay attention that this means that all the conditions asking whether `follower = nobody` don't make sense anymore: an empty agentset is different from `nobody`!

In fact, if you just make the above change, then click on `setup` and then run `count turtles with [follower = nobody]` in the Command Center, you would get 0.
Running instead `count turtles with [count follower = 0]` you would get all the turtles.

So the conditions with `nobody` will have to be changed accordingly; and, in particular, the one that was the object of your question will become a tidy

```
...
let candidate one-of (turtles-at xd yd) with [count follower < 2]
...
```

So, to bring back a bit of tidiness, let me put these three changes in their in-code logical order:

```
; The initial declaration when you create turtles:
...
set follower (turtle-set)
...

; The condition where you test how many followers a turtle has:
...
let candidate one-of (turtles-at xd yd) with [count follower < 2]
...

; The action of adding a follower:
...
ask candidate [set follower (turtle-set follower myself)]
...

; Plus changing other instances where the original code says 'with [follower = nobody]'.
```

---

*NOTE*

As you saw from the description of `turtle-set`, it is a very flexible primitive: basically it turns anything into an (turtle) agentset.
The most common way to create agentsets on the go, however, is using `with`. The logic is that a subgroup of an agentset is still an agentset; given that `with` can only be used on agentsets, what it gives you back can only be an agentset.
In our case, however, using `with` would have not been that tidy/simple.
The `follower` variable could have been initialised as an agentset quite easily using `with`:

```
ask candidate [set follower turtles with [who = [who] of myself]]
```

However, this only command would have set `follower` each time as the agentset containing the only turtle with that specific `who`, thus not helping with the intention of incrementing the numerosity of the agentset.
This is when things would have started to become more convoluted than just using `turtle-set`.

---

2. **Solution with list**

Another type of object that can be counted are lists. As you can imagine, you don't count lists with `count` but you can do it with `length`.

In this case, we just initialise `follower` as a list, add agents as items to the list using `lput` or `fput` (depending on how one wants to use the list), count the length of the list when checking the condition.
Changes mirror the ones we made in the agentset solution:

```
; The initial declaration when you create turtles:
...
set follower (list) ; or
set follower []
...

; The condition where you test how many followers a turtle has:
...
let candidate one-of (turtles-at xd yd) with [length follower < 2]
...

; The action of adding a follower:
...
ask candidate [set follower (lput myself follower)]
...

; Plus changing other instances where the original code says 'with [follower = nobody]'.
```

Using a list will be useful if you want to keep track of the order of turtles following the leader. In fact, while lists are ordered objects, agentsets are unordered (literally agents in an agentset come/act in a random order everytime you call that agentset).